How do I turn off spell checking?
Upon learning :set spell spelllang=en_us I now wish to learn how to turn spell off. Paging through all of :help spell proved fruitless.
How do I turn off spell checking?

As with all boolean options, you can :set nospell, or :set spell! to toggle. See :help options for more details.
I’m pretty sure the spell option is either buffer or window local, so I’d be inclined to use :setlocal out of habit.
